# 3D Vicsek Fractal Notebook

Tags: code-request, fractals

Can I get a link to a notebook that explores this fractal structure?

[image]

I am specifically asking for a url to a Mathematica notebook that generates and / or visualizes this type of fractal.

If that is not available, then what would be the Mathematica command(s) to generate this visualization? It doesn't have to rotate or be animated. This is just someone's animation that they made in PHP.

Comment: Please be more specific in order to increase your chances of useful responses.

Comment: For the visualization only: `p=Select[{-1,0,1}~Tuples~3,#.#<2&];Graphics3D[{Nest[#~Translate~p~Scale~(1/3)&,Cuboid[],3]}]`

Comment: @SimonWoods, looks like it's opened back up if you want to answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create the visualisation you can use [`Translate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html) and [`Scale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale.html) to iteratively create the object from a starting cube. Here `p` is a list of translation vectors and `f` is a function which applies the transformation. [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) is used to repeatedly apply `f` to an initial `Cuboid[]`.

```
p = {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};

f[x_] := Scale[Translate[x, p], 1/3]

Graphics3D[Nest[f, Cuboid[], 3], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

An alternative approach, which may be more useful for studying the structure, is to create it as a 3 dimensional array of ones and zeros. Here's one way to do that:

```
kernel = Normal @ SparseArray[(p + 2) -> 1];

g[x_] := ArrayFlatten[Map[kernel # &, x, {3}], 3]

Image3D[Nest[g, kernel, 2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a slight rewrite of Simon's solution that I picked up from [Brett](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/69):

```
t1 = Composition[ScalingTransform[{1/3, 1/3, 1/3}], TranslationTransform[#]] & /@
     {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};

tn = {#["AffineMatrix"], #["AffineVector"]} & /@
     Nest[Flatten[Outer[Composition, t1, #]] &, t1, 4]; (* fourth iterate *)

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[], tn]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Vicsek fractal]